# How to normalitation table include "question" data "true" or "false"

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I have 2 table name called "Users", "Mechine" and "Maintance".
on table "Machine" have colomn : id , name .
on table "users" have colomn   : id , name ,email,roles ,(etc)
on table "Maintance" have  : id,user_id ,mechine_id ,question ,status,date

i want to make view table like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVEpQ.jpg)

and if i click this action will show question data like this :[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0BPR.jpg)

now , i have a problem for show data based on id "machine" and date , like the picture

Comment: Paste your schema here. If you use images, people will unhappy about that :D

Comment: how i can build schema in here sir ?